# In C#, how to prevent XSS while allowing HTML input, including br's?

Tags: c#, string, xss

I've been using [MS's AntiXSS library](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5242) for a while now. Recently I decided to change the textareas in my site to be plain textareas (used to be WYSIWYG), and run a conversion on the newlines to br's.

Problem is, MS's AntiXSS library doesn't support this... it strips out the br's. I don't want to let the user's entry go directly into my DB unchecked. Without using the MS AntiXSS library, what's a reliable way to prevent XSS while allowing HTML input, including br's (in C#)?

Comment: Html encode your text then replace new lines by <br /> then save it to database. Disable XSS checks on this field. You Html encoded it, it's safe. (If I where you, I'll store it raw and encode while rendering)

Comment: Thanks for the idea Guillaume... Though I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 (razor) and can't figure out how to decode it back into HTML on the view. If I store it unencoded, them I'm basically storing the hacker's code.

I want the HTML to render... but remain safe. Wishful thinking? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I decided to store the raw HTML as-is, performing a replace on `Environment.Newlines` to `<br />` before storing it.

Then on the flip side, when showing it to visitors I use the MS AntiXSS code to clean it up. Not 100% the ideal way I'd like to do it, but gets the job done.

I do a bit of caching here to make sure it's not running through AntiXSS on every request too.

Comment: This doesn’t even work, since AntiXSS will replace your inserted `<br />`.

Comment: Yea, it replaces the `<br />` with `<br>` but it still works for my needs (though I wish it would output `<br />` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable your AntiXSS for this field and store directly the input from the user in your database.
That way, you'll be able to render this text on any output and not only HTML.

Now, when you want to display this text on an HTML page using ASP MVC Razor, you can use something like this :

```
@Html.Encode(Model.MyMultilineTextField).Replace(@"\n", "<br />")
```

Html.Encode will encode the text so Html tags are not interpreted and the XSS is not possible.
You may add an extension method on Html that does the transformation (whith replace) for you. You may also handle \r.

Comment: Using `@Html.Encode()` produces output like this: `&lt;b&gt;`, not rendered HTML in the view.

Comment: @Chad That’s why Guillaume replaces the newlines *after* escaping the text.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to get a copy of the AntiXSS' output? If so, run your input through the AntiXSS and then make the 
 replacement afterword and store the data yourself.

Comment: Sry, don't have it at this time. One problem stems from the fact that the output from AntiXSS removes all linebreaks too. So a simple .replace isn't effective.